# Error: Could not get list of graphs from Rexster

Tags: tomcat, titan, rexster

I have problems with Rexsters Doghouse. When I access the doghouse I just see a black page with a small menu and under that there is an error saying

```
 Error: Could not get list of graphs from Rexster
```

I've read that this problem can occur if one tries to access doghouse from an uri other than the base uri. My base uri is localhost:8080 and I've set this in the rexster.xml

```
 <rexster>
<http>
    <server-port>8080</server-port>
    <base-uri>http://localhost</base-uri>
    <enable-doghouse>true</enable-doghouse>
</http>
<graphs>
...
```

When I view the souce code in the doghouse page I can see that my changes have been applied since I can see:
        var GREMLIN_VERSION = "2.4.0";
       var BASE_URI = "http://
localhost:8080/"

(Note, the reason why I use server port 8080 is because I've deployed Rexster in Tomcat).

I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rexster doesn't officially support Tomcat deployment (though if you searching through the Gremlin users mailing list, you will find a few people who have gotten it to work).

That said, if you've managed to get so far that the `BASE_URI` is getting set in the JS, then I guess you are most of the way there. I would first validate that the REST API is properly serving and try to resolve:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/graphs
```

which should return something like with the default graph configurations:

```
{
  version: "x.y.z",
  name: "Rexster: A Graph Server",
  graphs: [
    "gratefulgraph",
    "tinkergraph",
    "emptygraph",
    "tinkergraph-readonly"
  ],
  queryTime: 0.480984,
  upTime: "0[d]:00[h]:01[m]:40[s]"
}
```

That's the route that Dog House should be calling to get the available graphs - I assume it isn't returning somehow.  If you can solve why that is a problem then you should be able get things working.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. localhost:8080/myprojectname/raw/graphs gives me that output so that seems to be in order. Any other ideas of what might be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe pop open your browser's developer tools and check the network traffic to see what URL isn't being resolved when the page loads.   I wonder if it isn't being constructed properly somehow.

Comment: thank you that solved my problem! I discovered that I had done a spelling misstake in my base uri. It is working now!